# Guardar una serie de Dataframes en una sola en python

Tags: csv, pandas, concat

estoy usando una función que utiliza todos los valores de una columna alojada en un archivo `.csv`  El resultado de la función es otra columna con valores numéricos que se aloja en un archivo `.csv` previamente creado.

Para seleccionar la columna utilizo `iloc[]` y en los corchetes añado el numero identificador de la columna que quiero analizar con mi función.

Para guardar el resultado defino una variable que comprende el dataframe generado (1 columna numerica),abro el archivo `.csv` concateno y guardo:

```
b = Resultado_de_funcion
a = pd.read_csv('Documento.csv')
c = pd.concat ([a,b],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
c.to_csv('/Users/Desktop/Documento.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Hasta aqui to va genial, porque genero mi dataFrame que luce así:

```
              0                  1                   2                  3
1   0.065674523303752   0.081470105150761   0.091769260076159   0.003526573075701
2   0.105065037258997   0.109204903445907   0.183093275351669   0.003306929861304
3   0.111578685238066   0.12082758028963    0.249087842460461   0.00289069546989
4   0.134153874890082   0.16609003496279    0.331391181462819   0.003440747831614
5   0.146779597122661   0.220918839369483   0.395566346515882   0.003117749159231
```

Hasta aquí todo va muy bien, solo que necesito analizar cientos y cientos de columnas, por tanto definí una lista que contiene los numero de las columnas a analizar y aplico la función haciendo un iteración:

```
List=[0,1,3,4,5,612,123,233,222,889]
for j in List:

    dfT = df2.loc[j]
```

Esto hace que mi función se aplique justo como quiero a cada columna, puedo ver los resultados en el shell de python, pero a la hora de ver los resultados en mi archivo `.csv` lo único que obtengo es la primera y la ultima columna.

```
           0                    889
1   0.065674523303752   0.081470105150761
2   0.105065037258997   0.109204903445907
3   0.111578685238066   0.12082758028963
4   0.134153874890082   0.16609003496279
```

Creo que ya estoy muy cerca de terminar, pero no encuentro como solucionar este problema, alguien me puede brindar nuevas ideas?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor seria crear un nuevo dataframe hecho de las columnas que quieres:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3] #crea una lista de los columnas

stuff = pd.DataFrame() #crea un nuevo dataframe

def keep(x):
    for e in lst:
         stuff[e] = test[e] #empareja la nueva columna con la columna del df
    return stuff

keep(test) #corre la funcion

         0         1           2           3
0   0.065675    0.105065    0.111579    0.134154
1   0.081470    0.109205    0.120828    0.166090
2   0.091769    0.183093    0.249088    0.331391
3   0.003527    0.003307    0.002891    0.003441


stuff.to_csv('stuff.csv') #guarda como csv
```

Comment: quiza soy acustumbrado de la brevidad del sitio ingles ;o. editado para claridad